# Multiple .NET Core Self Contained apps in single server performance

Tags: .net-core, kestrel

External software vendors is supplying 3 web apps written in .net core as self contained applications. I am running these self contained .net core apps in my linux system.

As each self contained app has same set of .net core libraries (.dlls), will these repeated dlls  in each self contained app's runtime be loaded in memory 3 times?

If thats the case, What is the optimal way to tackle this situation?